# Contact Management System Schema

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I'm looking for something I can reference in designing the database for a contact management system. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google suggests:

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/

Comment: More specifically, http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/contact_management/index.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, the site is now flagged as a malware source. :(

Comment: I'm not sure about OP but I'm looking for an answer that involves the user. It's a tricky problem to model because a user has an single identifying contact instance but at the same time has many contacts in their contact list.